Is there any experiment suitable for children to prove the photomolecular effect?

The photomolecular effect happens when a TM-polarized laser shines on the air–water interface at an angle such that an electrical field component perpendicular to the surface changes rapidly across the interface, leading to a net force acting on polar water molecular clusters. [[1][1]]

Though the source above cites a laser, the effect happens with any light, polarized or not. It's just more effective with polarized light (i.e. a laser).
From what I understood, when light hits the surface of liquid water, it causes molecules to detach from the surface, "causing evaporation in the absence of any source of heat[[2]][2]"
Can I make an experiment proving the existence of this effect for children, on a budget or, preferably, using common household / school items?
